# Pendulum Wave Period

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

Recently I've seen various videos showing the [pendulum wave effect](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVkdfJ9PkRQ). All of the videos which I have found have a pattern which repeats every $60\mathrm{s}$.

I am trying to work out the relationship between the period of the overall pattern and the difference in length between each of the pendulums.

From the small-angle approximation for the period of a simple pendulum, for each pendulum with period $T$ we have:

$$T\approx2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}},$$

Where $L$ is the length of the pendulum and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

If we take (say) $n$ pendulums, with lengths $L,L+d,\dots,L+(n-1)d$, then the pattern repeats at a period $t$ when all of $\frac{t}{L}\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}$, $\frac{t}{L+d}\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}$, $\dots$, $\frac{t}{L+(n-1)d}\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}$. where $\mathbb{Z}^{*}=\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

However, I'm not sure how to develop a direct relationship between $t$, $d$ and $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking equally spaced *lengths* will *not* reproduce the pendulum wave effect, simply because it's the *periods* that you want to fulfil commesurability conditions, and lengths and periods are not linearly related.

To get a pendulum wave, say you have $N$ pendula with lengths $l_n$. Then, as you know, the $n$th pendulum will have a period $$T_n=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{l_n}{g}}.$$ For the pendulum wave to work you need to prearrange a time $T$ at which all the pendulums come back into step. (Most demonstrations choose $T=60\text{ s}$, but this is not necessary.) For this to happen, $T$ needs to be an integer number of periods for each pendulum, so therefore
$$\boxed{nT_n=T.}$$
(This presupposes that we're using the number of periods in time $T$ to index the pendula. This is not strictly necessary but simplifies things, and people usually choose some relatively narrow range in $n$.)

Given the above relationship between $T_n$ and $l_n$, the commesurability condition reads
$$
l_n=g\left(\frac{T}{2\pi n}\right)^2
$$
in terms of the lengths $l_n$. Here $n$ should be an integer with $n\geq1$, but most demonstrations take $10\lesssim n\lesssim 30$ or so. Using very slow pendula, with low $n$, would mean the ratio of lengths between the first and the last pendulum would come out rather large.

Answer (score 1):

The question is equivalent to this:  given the physical state of the system at time $t_0$, $S(t_0)$, for what $T$ will $S(t_0)=S(t_0+T)$? That is,  for what $T$ will $$S_0(t)=S_0(t+T),$$$$
S_1(t)=S_1(t+T)$$$$...$$ hold, where $S_i(t)$ is the substate (namely, $\theta$) of the $i$th pendulum? Note that, letting $k=\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{g}}$, it is known that

$$S_0(t)=S_0(t+k \sqrt{L})$$
$$S_1(t)=S_1(t+k \sqrt{L+d})$$
$$S_2(t)=S_2(t+k \sqrt{L+2d})$$
$$...$$

When $S(t_0)=S(t_0+T)$, all the substates $S_n(t)=S_n(t+T)$ are pairwise equal.

Evidently, 
$k \sqrt{L+id}|T,(i \in [0,n])$ follows from this.
Or, letting $w=\frac{T}{k}, \sqrt{L+id}|w,$ $(i \in [0,n])$ .

There is not necessarily a solution for $w$, for example in the case where $L=5, i=0,1, d=2,$ $w=n \sqrt{5}, w=m \sqrt{7}$, which would give $\frac{n}{m}=\sqrt{\frac{7}{5}}$,$\text{  rational = irrational}$, a contradiction.

This isn't such a strange result. Imagine two non-interacting planets orbiting the sun with periods $\pi$ and $e$ years. When $t=0$, let them align so that $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$. Let them go, and they will never again align so that $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$. However, later they will *approximately* align at $0$ degrees.