# How to explain the motion of these pendulums?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, coupled-oscillators

Got very interested recently in a  video I saw running thru my feed:

https://www.facebook.com/PortalAECweb/videos/913996365374257/

Well, I got very intrigued about the physics of it and wanted to know your opinion about my guesses and how to proceed regarding them.
I think that basically this mad motion is due to the fact that there's some ratio between the length of these pendulums. I spent a little time thinking and before solving the movement equations thought that maybe I couldn't use the approximation for small angles for that and MAYBE the initial motion would be related to a trasient term (indicating time interval which the system is oscillating for angles greater then 5 degrees) and then go to these repetitive patterns, for smaller angles in which the system is pretty much conservative).
I thought about solving this numerically in Mathematica, plotting multiple pendulums with different lengths.

Comment: Have you considered the equation for the period of the pendulum, $T\approx2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63357/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the pendulums swing independently, but one can consider all of them together as a Hamiltonian system. The movie illustrates the Poincare recurrence theorem. It also illustrates quasi-periodic motion  on the Liouville torus in a completely integrable Hamiltonian system

Comment: Oh, give it a rest.